# TypeError: commands.options?.map() is not a function when setting slash commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

discord js v13.3.1

I have a set up with my bot that allows me to update and push slash commands via a command, deploy. The deploy command looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "deploy",
    description: "deploys slash commands",
    disabled: false,
    async execute(interaction, args, client) {
        if (interaction.author.id !== process.env.OWNERID) return interaction.reply('You must be the owner to use this!');

        const cmds = client.commands
            .filter(command => command.slash)
            .map(command => {
                let {
                    name,
                    description = "missing description",
                    options = [],
                    slash = false,
                    defaultPermission = true,
                    slashPermissions = [],
                } = command;
                if (typeof name === "string") name = [name];
                const cmd = { name: name[0], description, options, defaultPermission, permissions: slashPermissions };
                return cmd;
            });

            await setCommands(interaction.guild?.commands)
                .then(interaction.reply(`Registered ${cmds.length} commands to this guild!`));


        async function setCommands(commandManager) {
            const appCommands = await commandManager.set(
                commandManager?.guild ? cmds : cmds.filter(cmd => !cmd.permissions.length)
            );
            if (commandManager?.guild) {
                const fullPermissions = appCommands
                    .map(appCommand => {
                        const permissions = cmds.find(cmd => cmd.name === appCommand.name).permissions;
                        return { id: appCommand.id, permissions };
                    })
                    .filter(appCommand => appCommand.permissions.length);
                await commandManager.permissions.set({ fullPermissions });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I stopped work on my bot awhile back, and now am trying to update the rest of my commands to have slash functionality. I have slash commands registered to my guild, so this command has worked in the past as is. Now, when I try to deploy my slash commands, I am getting this error in my console:

```
main\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:246
      options: command.options?.map(o => ApplicationCommand.transformOption(o)),
                                ^

TypeError: command.options?.map is not a function
    at Function.transformCommand (main\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:246:33)
    at main\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:163:48
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (main\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:163:22)
    at setCommands (main\commands\admin\deploy.js:34:54)
    at Object.execute (main\commands\admin\deploy.js:29:19)
    at module.exports (main\events\guild\messageCreate.js:28:51)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

For reference, my commands are built as such:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "move",
    description: "Move all users from one vc to another",
    usage: `\`${process.env.PREFIX}move <vc1> <vc2>\``,
    alias: ["mv"],
    disabled: false,
    slash: true,
    options: [
        {
            name: 'target',
            type: 'CHANNEL',
            channelTypes: ['GUILD_VOICE'],
            description: 'Channel to move users from',
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: 'destination',
            type: 'CHANNEL',
            channelTypes: ['GUILD_VOICE'],
            description: 'Channel to move users into',
            required: true
        }
    ],
    permission: ['MOVE_MEMBERS'],
    async execute(interaction, args){ 
    }
}
```

Is this an issue with how I am building my options blocks in my commands themselves, or how I am parsing them to send to guildCommandManager? I'm assuming the former because the error is a TypeError, but I am historically bad at working with maps and objects, so I could be wrong, and it's hard for me to figure out since the error is being thrown from the djs module and not my code itself

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the rest method which you can view the code of it here on the discord.js guide.

https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.html#command-deployment-script

You can create global commands with: applicationCommands
and create local commands for 1 server with: applicationGuildCommands